# Provide equivalence classes for a piece $(0;1]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $A , B  \subseteq \mathbb{R_+} \ A\sim B \iff \exists p \in \mathbb{R_+} B=\{x * p: x\in A\}$ be an equivalence relation. Provide equivalence classes for an interval $(0;1]$.

As for me, I think it's a set of all positive reals, but not sure. Am I right?

Comment: Notice the elements of $A$ and $B$ are sets of real numbers, not real numbers. So an equivalence class should be a set of sets of real numbers.

Comment: @aschepler but how can it be negative if A B and p are posiitves ?

Comment: No negative numbers are involved here.

Comment: @aschepler how can you multiply positive by positive and get negative? It is steted that A B and p are from $\mathbb{R_+}$

Comment: Why are you bringing up negative at all?

Comment: @aschepler you said its just a set of real numbers

Comment: "(A) set of real numbers" just means a set of some real numbers. A set of positive real numbers is also a set of real numbers. I didn't say "the set of real numbers" or "all real numbers".